# Dynamically adding column values based on combo box selection

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help. It seems what I have written in code does not accomplish what I am trying to do here.

The objective would be to have 2 userform combo boxes one for the (floor) values which are manually added once [3,4,5] and the other combo boxes (offices) in which values are dynamically added based on the selection made in the floor selection box.

Let's say for example that if I chose the value [3] in my floor combo box that the office combo box would contain the following values:

```
A-01
A-02
A-03
A-04
A-05
A-06
A-07
A-08
```

I thought this code would work but it doesn't:

```
'Cells(row, col)

Private Sub floor_Change()
    lRow = Sheets("Office Spaces").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With Sheets("Office Spaces")
        For i = 2 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = UserForm1.floor.Value Then
                UserForm1.office.AddItem .Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Here's what the data looks in my excel sheet:

[image]

Comment: try `debug.? UserForm1.floor.Value` before, make sure you definitely have what you are expecting.  Also, what does go into the combo if anything?

Comment: What is the problem? Is it the wrong values or not being populated at all or?

Comment: you should clear your office combo box before adding items. First action in `floor_Change` should be `UserForm1.office.Clear` otherwise it will add more and more items to the combo box each time you change the floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Cells(row, col)

Private Sub floor56_Change()

UserForm1.office.Clear

Dim sh
Dim rw

Set sh = Sheets("Office Spaces")

For Each rw In sh.Rows

  If sh.Cells(rw.row, 1).Text = UserForm1.floor.Value Then

    UserForm1.office.AddItem (sh.Cells(rw.row, 2).Value)

  End If

Next rw

End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub floor_Change()

    If UserForm1.floor.Value <> "" Then

        UserForm1.office.Clear

        Dim ws
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Office Spaces")

        Dim rng
        Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")

        For Each cell In rng

            If cell.Text = UserForm1.floor.Value Then

                UserForm1.office.AddItem (cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)

            End If

        Next cell

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend never to use `Variants` if possible (`ws`, `rng`). Proper variable type specification is a very good practice. Also I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. And declare *all* variables. • Also `For Each cell In rng` where `rng` is the whole column A will take an unnecessarily long time. Better reduce it to the range where data is in (and omit all the blanks in the end of column A).

Comment: Also you should explain what you did and why. Code answers without text or explanation in most cases are poor answers.